# JavaScript: getting part of string using substring

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in JavaScript:

```
var text = "i HATE you[i LOVE you]"
```

The code below originated from VB. I've checked it against [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) but I cannot see why it won't work.

```
var test = text.Substring(text.IndexOf("[") + 1, text.IndexOf("]") - text.IndexOf("[") - 1);
document.write(test);
```

Comment: What are you trying to get? `"i HATE you"` or `"[i LOVE you]"`?

Comment: What is your purpose? What do you expect to see as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is the "end index", not the "length". Or you can use regex.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is case sensetive, so it doesn't have any `Substring` or `IndexOf` methods, it has `substring` and `indexOf` methods. However, the .NET method `SubString` corresponds to the Javascript method `substr`:

```
var test = text.substr(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.indexOf("]") - text.indexOf("[") - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me that substr is the .NET equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**Reasons why your current solution fails:**

- javascript is case-sensitive you trying to call `String.IndexOf` won't work, instead you **have to** write it as `indexOf`.
- same reason as previous list entry, `SubString` should be written as `substring`, in the method you are using it seems like you are looking for `substr` (because of your arguments).

**Alternative solutions**

There are several ways to simplify your method of getting the text inbetween `[`and `]`, I wrote three examples below.

```
 text.substring (text.indexOf ('[')+1, text.lastIndexOf (']'));

 text.substr (n=text.indexOf('[')+1, text.indexOf (']')-n);

 text.split (/\[|\]/)[1];

 text.match (/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what output you're expecting, but the obvious issue is that your casing is wrong. Method names are case sensitive. You'd need this instead:

```
text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.indexOf("]") - text.indexOf("[") - 1);
```